# Why isn't json.dumps() using my custom classes JSON serialiser?

Tags: python, json

I have a Python3 class defined like so:

```
class Principal:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

    def default(self, o):
        print("default called")
        return {"id":self.id, "princpal":self.name}

    ...
```

If I create an instance of this class:
`new_principal = Principal("p_1", "Ted")` and call `json.dumps(new_principal)` the expected behaviour of the dumps functions would be to use my classes `default()` in order to return a dict that can be converted to JSON.

This is not happening however, it does not attempt to call my classes `default()` and so returns an error that the class is not serializable.

The docs states ``` Implement this method in a subclass such that it returns a serializable object for ``o``, or calls the base implementation (to raise a ``TypeError``). ``` which I believe I have done, yet it does not appear to call the classes defult().

Why does is this happening? If I specify the default using `json.dumps(new_principal, Principal(new_principal))` then it parses successfully.

I can't see why my function isn't being called.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's simply not how `json.dump` works. The passage you've quoted about `default` is for subclassing the JSON serializer, which you're not doing.

If you're just using `json.dump`, you'll need to pass a `default=...` function to it that does the Right Thing, e.g.

```
class Principal:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

    def to_json(self):
        return {"id": self.id, "princpal": self.name}


def default_dumper(o):
    if hasattr(o, "to_json"):
        return o.to_json()
    raise TypeError(f"Unable to JSONify {o}")


# ...
data = json.dumps(new_principal, default=default_dumper)
```

Comment: Ah, thats a misunderstanding on my part and I see where I went wrong. But now I have the issue of that json.dumps() is being called from a library that I'm using, meaning I don't have a way to pass the default=default_dumper to the dumps - is there a way around that or would I have to edit the libary to use my dumper?

Comment: What library is that?

Comment: It's the [PyVis](https://pyvis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library for creating visualising graphs.

Comment: If it's this segment: https://github.com/WestHealth/pyvis/blob/b49d43ea266bcb93ace3d521486bd1353663c8cb/pyvis/network.py#L388-L393 it already supports a `to_json()` function...

Comment: It's the [show() function](https://github.com/WestHealth/pyvis/blob/b49d43ea266bcb93ace3d521486bd1353663c8cb/pyvis/network.py#L465). When I run ```get_network_data()``` on the graph of objects it parses fine and outputs seemingly fine.

Comment: Could you add the full traceback to the error you're getting into your original post?